Random network issue
To give some context, I have a desktop computer that, for the past few weeks, has been experiencing network problems at certain times during the day (often every 30 minutes, but sometimes not for 3 to 5 hours). The connection to any type of network is lost for 1 to 2 minutes (including both the router and mobile tethering).
I’ve tried quite a few things, but it doesn’t seem to be enough.
First, I tested with two network cards purchased for this purpose: one Wi-Fi and one Ethernet. Previously, I was connected directly via the motherboard.
I also tried fixing the issue by resetting my operating system and assigning a static IP address.

Motherboard: PRIME Z590-A
Processor: i7-11700K
Operating System: Windows 11 Home, 24H2
Wi-Fi Dongle: TP-Link AC 1300
Network Card: TP-Link PCIe 2.5 Gigabit TX201


Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Can you reach/ping your router? What does the router say during those periods? Any logging events? New public IP afterwards?

do you have other devices that are (or are not) working fine during this period? any difference between LAN-to-LAN vs LAN-to-WAN network use?

To address the different questions, I tested pinging the router at 192.168.1.254, but the issue persists. I also tried with another computer, and the problem did not occur. I recently reset the BIOS to its default settings, modifying only the RAM frequency and enabling TPM 2.0 to reinstall Windows. However, despite this, the issue remains. I have not yet performed the Windows updates or the firmware updates.

Can someone help me

Do other devices connected to the same network experience the same or similar symptoms?

Hello, I'm coming back a bit late, but I have an additional piece of information that makes things more strange but could perhaps help me. I'm having connectivity issues only with my IPv4 addresses and not with IPv6. Sites like YouTube and Google work fine.

And no, music2myear is the only device that has a problem...

The only device I cannot communicate with in IPv4 during the issue is the network gateway. The other Ethernet devices can communicate properly. Regarding Wi-Fi devices, the problem occurs only on my PC: the other device can successfully perform the pings.
